# ignite query cache with value as list of objects

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I am using ignite cache with key as String and value as Collection of objects (similar type) say List.

Now i would like to query on the students stored in cache let's say 5 top scored students.

defined the configuration as below

```
CacheConfiguration<String, List<Student>> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<String, List<Student>>("students");
ignite = Ignition.start("/usr/localc/ignite/examples/config/example-ignite.xml");
cfg.setIndexedTypes(String.class, List.class);
```

Now I fired a query like

```
SqlFieldsQuery qry = new SqlFieldsQuery("select count(*) from Person");
```

Then got exception like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.opt.GridH2Table$ScanIndex.getCost(Lorg/h2/engine/Session;[I[Lorg/h2/table/TableFilter;ILorg/h2/result/SortOrder;Ljava/util/HashSet;)D
at org.h2.table.TableFilter.getBestPlanItem(TableFilter.java:203)
at org.h2.table.Plan.calculateCost(Plan.java:123)
at org.h2.command.dml.Optimizer.testPlan(Optimizer.java:183)
at org.h2.command.dml.Optimizer.calculateBestPlan(Optimizer.java:79)
at org.h2.command.dml.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:242)
at org.h2.command.dml.Select.preparePlan(Select.java:1014)
at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:878)
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:259)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:560)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:501)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1202)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:290)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepareStatement(IgniteH2Indexing.java:406)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryTwoStep(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1121)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$2.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:732)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$2.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:730)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:1666)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.queryTwoStep(GridQueryProcessor.java:730)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:700)
at com.tcs.enm.processor.Main.main(Main.java:47)
```

Can any one help me how to query ???

Answer (score 3):

To execute such query you should store each `Student` as a separate entry. `Student` class should have all the annotations defining fields and indexes and the cache configuration should look like this:

```
cfg.setIndexedTypes(String.class, Student.class);
```

For more details refer to this documentation: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-queries

Comment: In my use case there are couple of millions of students... due to other business cases I need to have value as list of Students and the key may be year, university, college, etc..

Comment: Why do you want these to be a keys? Add them as value fields and configure indexes for fast search.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone in the future who has this issue, this error message is likely due to using an incorrect version of H2.

http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/Exception-while-trying-to-access-cache-via-JDBC-API-td8648.html#a8651

If you're using Ignite 1.7, you need h2database 1.4.191.
Note that h2database 1.4.192 WILL give you the exception in the question because there are some changes in 192 which Ignite wasn't made to handle

I went through my packages and changed the H2 version to 1.4.191 and it fixed my problems.